# Why I can't decompile this ARM function?

Tags: ida, arm, firmware-analysis

I have an ARM (thumb) function from Nokia's firmware:

```
ROM:10A5409C srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler        ; CODE XREF: srv_opp_event_hdlr+1C6↑p
ROM:10A5409C
ROM:10A5409C var_18          = -0x18
ROM:10A5409C var_14          = -0x14
ROM:10A5409C var_10          = -0x10
ROM:10A5409C
ROM:10A5409C                 PUSH            {R1-R5,LR}
ROM:10A5409E                 LDR             R1, =srv_oppc_p
ROM:10A540A0                 LDR             R4, [R1,#(srv_opps_p - 0xF00E4880)]
ROM:10A540A2                 ADDS            R4, #0xC
ROM:10A540A4                 LDRB            R1, [R4,#1]
ROM:10A540A6                 CMP             R1, #9
ROM:10A540A8                 BEQ             locret_10A540BE
ROM:10A540AA                 CMP             R1, #0xA
ROM:10A540AC                 BEQ             locret_10A540BE
ROM:10A540AE                 CMP             R1, #3
ROM:10A540B0                 BEQ             locret_10A540BE
ROM:10A540B2                 CMP             R1, #8
ROM:10A540B4                 BEQ             loc_10A540C0
ROM:10A540B6                 LDRB            R0, [R4]
ROM:10A540B8                 MOVS            R1, #0x50 ; 'P'
ROM:10A540BA                 BL              sub_10B31478
ROM:10A540BE
ROM:10A540BE locret_10A540BE                         ; CODE XREF: srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+C↑j
ROM:10A540BE                                         ; srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+10↑j ...
ROM:10A540BE                 POP             {R1-R5,PC}
ROM:10A540C0 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROM:10A540C0
ROM:10A540C0 loc_10A540C0                            ; CODE XREF: srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+18↑j
ROM:10A540C0                 MOVS            R1, #0x3000
ROM:10A540C4                 ADDS            R1, R4, R1
ROM:10A540C6                 LDRB            R1, [R1,#0x1C]
ROM:10A540C8                 CMP             R1, #0
ROM:10A540CA                 BEQ             loc_10A540DA
ROM:10A540CC                 MOVS            R0, #0x6000
ROM:10A540D0                 ADDS            R0, R4, R0
ROM:10A540D2                 LDR             R0, [R0,#0x24]
ROM:10A540D4                 BL              sub_10A6CCC4
ROM:10A540D8
ROM:10A540D8 locret_10A540D8                         ; CODE XREF: srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+66↓j
ROM:10A540D8                 POP             {R1-R5,PC}
ROM:10A540DA ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROM:10A540DA
ROM:10A540DA loc_10A540DA                            ; CODE XREF: srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+2E↑j
ROM:10A540DA                 MOVS            R1, #0x260
ROM:10A540DE                 ADDS            R1, R0, R1
ROM:10A540E0                 LDRH            R3, [R1,#0x10]
ROM:10A540E2                 CMP             R3, #0
ROM:10A540E4                 BEQ             loc_10A54104
ROM:10A540E6                 LDRB            R1, [R0,#0x16]
ROM:10A540E8                 MOVS            R2, #0
ROM:10A540EA                 STR             R2, [SP,#0x18+var_14]
ROM:10A540EC                 STR             R1, [SP,#0x18+var_18]
ROM:10A540EE                 MOVS            R1, #0x240
ROM:10A540F2                 ADDS            R0, R0, R1
ROM:10A540F4                 LDR             R1, [R0,#0x2C]
ROM:10A540F6                 MOVS            R2, R3
ROM:10A540F8                 LDR             R0, [R4,#8]
ROM:10A540FA                 ADD             R3, SP, #0x18+var_10
ROM:10A540FC                 BL              srv_opps_write_file
ROM:10A54100                 CMP             R0, #0
ROM:10A54102                 BLT             locret_10A540D8
ROM:10A54104
ROM:10A54104 loc_10A54104                            ; CODE XREF: srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+48↑j
ROM:10A54104                 LDR             R0, [R4,#8]
ROM:10A54106                 CMP             R0, #0
ROM:10A54108                 BEQ             loc_10A54112
ROM:10A5410A                 BLX             $Ven$AT$L$$FS_Close
ROM:10A5410E                 MOVS            R0, #0
ROM:10A54110                 STR             R0, [R4,#8]
ROM:10A54112
ROM:10A54112 loc_10A54112                            ; CODE XREF: srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+6C↑j
ROM:10A54112                 LDR             R0, [R4,#4]
ROM:10A54114                 BL              sub_10A6CB64
ROM:10A54118                 POP             {R1-R5,PC}
ROM:10A54118 ; End of function srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler
ROM:10A54118
ROM:10A54118 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ROM:10A5411A                 ALIGN 4
ROM:10A5411C off_10A5411C    DCD srv_oppc_p          ; DATA XREF: srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+2↑r
ROM:10A54120
```

When I press <kbd>F5</kbd> to decompile the function to pseudocode, it shows nothing:

[image: decompile view]

While I am able to decompile other functions normally, without any problems. For example, **still that function**, but **on another** Nokia firmware:

```
ALICE:1052B91C ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
ALICE:1052B91C
ALICE:1052B91C
ALICE:1052B91C srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler        ; CODE XREF: srv_opp_event_hdlr+1C0↑p
ALICE:1052B91C
ALICE:1052B91C var_18          = -0x18
ALICE:1052B91C var_14          = -0x14
ALICE:1052B91C
ALICE:1052B91C                 PUSH            {R2-R6,LR}
ALICE:1052B91E                 LDR             R1, =srv_oppc_p
ALICE:1052B920                 LDR             R4, [R1,#(srv_opps_p - 0xF00A9108)] ; srv_opps_inst
ALICE:1052B922                 ADDS            R4, #0xC
ALICE:1052B924                 LDRB            R1, [R4,#(byte_F0208859 - 0xF0208858)]
ALICE:1052B926                 CMP             R1, #9
ALICE:1052B928                 BEQ             locret_1052B970
ALICE:1052B92A                 CMP             R1, #0xA
ALICE:1052B92C                 BEQ             locret_1052B970
ALICE:1052B92E                 CMP             R1, #3
ALICE:1052B930                 BEQ             locret_1052B970
ALICE:1052B932                 CMP             R1, #8
ALICE:1052B934                 BEQ             loc_1052B93C
ALICE:1052B936                 LDRB            R0, [R4]
ALICE:1052B938                 MOVS            R1, #0x50 ; 'P'
ALICE:1052B93A                 B               loc_1052B96C
ALICE:1052B93C ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALICE:1052B93C
ALICE:1052B93C loc_1052B93C                            ; CODE XREF: srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+18↑j
ALICE:1052B93C                 MOVS            R1, #0x240
ALICE:1052B940                 ADDS            R1, R0, R1
ALICE:1052B942                 LDR             R5, [R1,#0x2C]
ALICE:1052B944                 MOVS            R1, #0x260
ALICE:1052B948                 ADDS            R1, R0, R1
ALICE:1052B94A                 LDRH            R3, [R1,#0x10]
ALICE:1052B94C                 CMP             R3, #0
ALICE:1052B94E                 BEQ             loc_1052B968
ALICE:1052B950                 LDRB            R1, [R0,#0x16]
ALICE:1052B952                 MOVS            R2, #0
ALICE:1052B954                 STR             R2, [SP,#0x18+var_14]
ALICE:1052B956                 STR             R1, [SP,#0x18+var_18]
ALICE:1052B958                 MOVS            R2, R3
ALICE:1052B95A                 LDR             R0, [R4,#(dword_F0208860 - 0xF0208858)]
ALICE:1052B95C                 MOVS            R1, R5
ALICE:1052B95E                 MOVS            R3, #0
ALICE:1052B960                 BL              srv_opps_write_file
ALICE:1052B964                 CMP             R0, #0
ALICE:1052B966                 BLT             locret_1052B970
ALICE:1052B968
ALICE:1052B968 loc_1052B968                            ; CODE XREF: srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+32↑j
ALICE:1052B968                 LDRB            R0, [R4]
ALICE:1052B96A                 MOVS            R1, #0
ALICE:1052B96C
ALICE:1052B96C loc_1052B96C                            ; CODE XREF: srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+1E↑j
ALICE:1052B96C                 BL              srv_opps_push_rsp
ALICE:1052B970
ALICE:1052B970 locret_1052B970                         ; CODE XREF: srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+C↑j
ALICE:1052B970                                         ; srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+10↑j ...
ALICE:1052B970                 POP             {R2-R6,PC}
ALICE:1052B970 ; End of function srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler
ALICE:1052B970
ALICE:1052B970 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALICE:1052B972                 ALIGN 4
ALICE:1052B974 off_1052B974    DCD srv_oppc_p          ; DATA XREF: srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler+2↑r
```

decompiled to

```cpp
int __fastcall srv_opps_normal_push_ind_handler(int result, int a2, int a3)
{
  int *v3; // r4
  int v4; // r1
  int v5; // r0
  int v6; // r1

  v3 = srv_opps_p + 3;
  v4 = *((unsigned __int8 *)srv_opps_p + 13);
  if ( v4 != 9 && v4 != 10 && v4 != 3 )
  {
    if ( v4 != 8 )
    {
      v5 = *(unsigned __int8 *)v3;
      v6 = 80;
      return srv_opps_push_rsp(v5, v6, a3);
    }
    if ( !*(_WORD *)(result + 624)
      || (result = srv_opps_write_file(v3[2], *(_DWORD *)(result + 620), *(unsigned __int16 *)(result + 624), 0),
          result >= 0) )
    {
      v5 = *(unsigned __int8 *)v3;
      v6 = 0;
      return srv_opps_push_rsp(v5, v6, a3);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

I also tried export the whole database's pseudocode to a C file, but still same result on that function.

Why it doesn't decompile?

Comment: This sounds like a good question for Hex-Rays support.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the `segment name` of your firmwares. In the first firmware the segment name is `ROM`, which means the segment is read only, but in your second firmware the name is `ALICE`, which makes no restrictions on writing data to the segment.